# Three.js secret: I cannot run any example

Tags: three.js

I'm beginner in WebGL

I follow the examples and I always get error.

Why [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/naudwtaL/) does not work.

While it works for the others with [similar code](http://jsfiddle.net/nnm64/2/)?

```
(function() {
    // Set basic some variables.
    var documentWidth = document.body.clientWidth,
        documentHeight = document.body.clientHeight,
        viewAngle = 45,
        drawNear = 0.1,
        drawFar = 10000,
        aspectRatio = documentWidth / documentHeight,
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(),
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

    ... follow jsfiddle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not include three.js. https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/naudwtaL/1/

```
https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js
```

The older design of jsfiddle made it easy to include some external libraries by having a combobox for you to select from.

[image: old design]

The new design has moved these options as seen in the below picture.

[image: new design]

While you can add three.js via the combobox selector thing, as of now you can only include three.js r54 which is quite old, so you are probably better off including it the way I did in the fiddle I linked to.

Comment: Thanks, but I wondering how it was added into this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nnm64/2/)? I do not see any external link there.

Comment: You use to be able to select from a range of libraries to include in your fiddle with three.js being one of them. JSFiddle.net seems to have gone through a redesign which not longer shows this external library selection but still includes these selected libraries. You can see what I am talking about by taking a look at the [image at the top of this page](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html)

Comment: I just found that the frameworks selection is still there, just hard to find. I'll update my answer.